# Display all available sheets in combobox, except the hidden ones, (loop through sheets add to list) VBA

Tags: vba, loops, combobox, visible

Okay genius hive mind, what am I doing wrong this time?

```
 'wb and ws dimmed in module level declarations...
 Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 wb.activate

Dim I As Integer, sheetCount As Integer

sheetCount = wb.Worksheets.Count
 
 Dim sheetNum As Integer
 sheetNum = 1
 With cboCopyFromSheet 'combobox
 
     For I = 0 To sheetCount - 1 
    'not sure why the capital 'I' describing an object?
    'copied from MS documentation
     
     If wb.Worksheets(sheetNum).Visible = True Then
          
       .AddItem wb.Worksheets(sheetNum).Name, I '<----Error
     End If
      sheetNum = sheetNum + 1
    
     Next I
     
   End With
```

Weirdly this only happens when I = 9 and sheetnum = 10
None of the sheets are currently hidden ( but some will be )
sheet 10 happens to be a blank sheet...
We are very confucius.

Error thrown is "invalid argument"
Any Clues?

Comment: When you speak about an error, it must be associated to the code line throwing it. No need of any `sheetNum` variable, since you iterate between sheets and have `I` instead.  Please, check the answer I posted...

Comment: `.AddItem wb.Worksheets(sheetNum).Name, I` doesn't need the last argument (`I`)...

Answer (score 0):

Try the next (simple) code, please. Creating the habit to use combobox `List` property, will be helpful when you will need to rapidly load a big range (multi-columns, too):

```
Sub testLoadComboSheetsNames()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, arrSh As Variant, k As Long
  
    ReDim arrSh(1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.count)
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Visible = True Then k = k + 1: arrSh(k) = sh.Name
    Next
    ReDim Preserve arrSh(k)
    cboCopyFromSheet.list = arrSh
End Sub
```

In order to work, your code must look like the next:

```
Sub testLoadComboShbis()
 Dim i As Long, wb As Workbook
 Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 For i = 1 To wb.Worksheets.count
     If wb.Worksheets(i).Visible = True Then
         cboCopyFromSheet.AddItem wb.Worksheets(i).Name
     End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach to Fane's answer, using the [For Each](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement) statement.

```
Sub Whatever()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
       If ws.Visible Then combo.AddItem ws.Name
    Next
    
End Sub
```